# Regex to capture a number if not followed by a hyphen or the word "to"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I would like to use a regex to capture individual numbers in the text as long as it is not followed by or following "-" or "to". For example:

1. This is an example where numbers 500 - 600 should not be captured separately.
2. This is another example where numbers 500 to 600 should not be captured separately.
3. This is an example where 600 should be captured.

So in examples 1 and 2 numbers 500 and 600 should not be captured separately because - and to are included in between the numbers 500 - 600, but the whole string should be captured "500 - 600".
In example 3 number 600 should be captured. My problem is that numbers in example 1 and 2 are captured separately, while I need to capture the whole string "500 - 600" when "-" is included, and capture the numbers separately if is not.

I tried something like this but it does not work. I guess I need lookahead and behind?

```
((?:[\p{P}-[-.,\]]\s*|to\s*)\d+\.?\d*(?:\s*[\p{P}-[-.,\]]\s*|\s*to))
```

Comment: You left examples blank.

Comment: Could you please be more specific: what are you doing with this regex? What I am driving at, you might be using a simple technique - to match and capture what you want, and just match what you do not want - [`/\d+ *(?:-|to) *\d+|(\d+)/`](http://rubular.com/r/uSr9p8Kvjh)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I added more explanation because my question was not clear. I want to capture -|to but also be able to capture the numbers individually if no -|to is following.

Comment: Does it mean it is even simpler? [`s.scan(/\d+ *(?:-|to) *\d+|\d+/)`](https://ideone.com/K8hT0o). Why are you using `\p{P}`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you. It seems to work great. This way it wont capture 500, 600 separately if -,to are in between right? It will only capture 500-600

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an alternation group and place the more specific `number - number` or `number to number` pattern as the first alternative branch, and only match standalone numbers in the second branch:

```
s.scan(/\d+ *(?:-|to) *\d+|\d+/)
```

or - to match any whitespace

```
s.scan(/\d+\s*(?:-|to)\s*\d+|\d+/)
```

See [Ruby demo](https://ideone.com/K8hT0o)

Note that once the first alternative matches, the second one is not tried since this is how NFA regex alternation works. See [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager* section at the *Alternation with The Vertical Bar or Pipe Symbol*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html).

**Details**:

The range alternative branch:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespaces
- `(?:-|to)` - a `-` or `to` character sequence
- `\s*\d+` - 0+ whitespaces and then 1+ digits

The standalone number alternative branch:

- `\d+` - 1 or more digits.

**NOTE** (based on the [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39484921/regex-to-capture-a-number-if-there-is-no-or-to-lookahead/39485500?noredirect=1#comment66290206_39485500)):

Instead of `-`, you might want to use `\p{Pd}`, a [*Punctuation, Dash* unicode character category](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pd/index.htm) that matches

```
Character   Name                                    Browser
U+002D      HYPHEN-MINUS                            -
U+058A      ARMENIAN HYPHEN                         ֊
U+05BE      HEBREW PUNCTUATION MAQAF                ־
U+1400      CANADIAN SYLLABICS HYPHEN               ᐀
U+1806      MONGOLIAN TODO SOFT HYPHEN              ᠆
U+2010      HYPHEN                                  ‐
U+2011      NON-BREAKING HYPHEN                     ‑
U+2012      FIGURE DASH                             ‒
U+2013      EN DASH                                 –
U+2014      EM DASH                                 —
U+2015      HORIZONTAL BAR                          ―
U+2E17      DOUBLE OBLIQUE HYPHEN                   ⸗
U+2E1A      HYPHEN WITH DIAERESIS                   ⸚
U+2E3A      TWO-EM DASH                             ⸺
U+2E3B      THREE-EM DASH                           ⸻
U+2E40      DOUBLE HYPHEN                           ⹀
U+301C      WAVE DASH                               〜
U+3030      WAVY DASH                               〰
U+30A0      KATAKANA-HIRAGANA DOUBLE HYPHEN         ゠
U+FE31      PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL EM DASH  ︱
U+FE32      PRESENTATION FORM FOR VERTICAL EN DASH  ︲
U+FE58      SMALL EM DASH                           ﹘
U+FE63      SMALL HYPHEN-MINUS                      ﹣
U+FF0D      FULLWIDTH HYPHEN-MINUS                  －
```

Comment: You might want to use '\p{Pd}' instead of '-' so that you capture em and en dashes as well as hyphens. I don't know where the data is coming from but if it's user-input then there's always *someone* who's going to copy out of a word document

Comment: @DaveMongoose: That sounds helpful, I added a note with the description of what `\p{Pd}` matches to the answer.