# Hyphen character '-' creating issues when using regular expressions for BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, regex, beautifulsoup

I am learning how to webscrape with python using a Wikepedia article. I managed to get the data I needed, the tables, by using the .get_text() method on the table rows ().

I am cleaning up the data in Pandas and one of the routines involves getting the date a book or movie was published. Since there are many ways in which this can occur such as:
(1986)
(1986-1989)
(1986-present)

Currently, I am using the code below which works on a test sentence:

```
# get the first columns of row 19 from the table and get its text
test = data_collector[19].find_all('td')[0]
text = test.get_text()
#create and test the pattern
pattern = re.compile('\(\d\d\d\d\)|\(\d\d\d\d-\d\d\d\d\)|\(\d\d\d\d-[ Ppresent]*\)')
re.findall(pattern, 'This is Agent (1857), the years were (1987-1868), which lasted from (1678- Present)')
```

I get the expected output on the test sentence.

```
['(1857)', '(1987-1868)', '(1678- Present)']
```

However, when I test it on a particular piece of text from the wiki article '**The Adventures of Sherlock Holmes (1891–1892) (series), (1892) (novel), Arthur Conan Doyle\n**', I am able to extract (1892), but NOT (1891-1892).

```
text = test.get_text()
re.findall(pattern, text)
o/p: ['(1892)']
```

Even as I type this, I can see that the hyphen that I am using and the one on the text are different. I am sure that this is the issue and was hoping if someone could tell me what this particular symbol is called and how I can actually "type" it using my keyboard.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you sure there is a hyphen and not em-dash? Try `re.compile(r'\(\d{4}(?:[\s–—-]+(?:\d{4}|present))?\)', re.I)`. See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSM7JU/3).

Comment: If you can use [`regex`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex), you can use the Unicode character category `\p{Pd}` to match all dashes - see https://stackoverflow.com/q/1832893/3001761

Comment: I agree with @Wiktor, the character may not be exactly as it appears to be. Another solution would be to replace the '-' with '\S'. Meaning match any non white space character

Comment: `\p{Pd}` includes a lot of [symbols similar to hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39485500/3832970). Some do not look like hyphens though. Use `\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D` instead of hyphen/dashes then. Or, to match any non-word char, probably, other than `(` and `)`, `[^\w()]` => `re.compile(r'\(\d{4}(?:[^\w()]+(?:\d{4}|present))?\)', re.I)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you! Your solution works flawlessly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest enhancing the pattern to search for the most common hyphens, `-`, `–` and `—`, and fix the `present` pattern from a character class to a char sequence (so as not to match `sent` with `[ Ppresent]*`):

```
re.compile(r'\(\d{4}(?:[\s–—-]+(?:\d{4}|present))?\)', re.I)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BSM7JU/3). Note that `re.I` flag will make the regex match in a case insensitive way.

**Details**

- `\(` - a `(`
- `\d{4}` - four digits (`{4}` is a limiting quantifier that repeats the pattern it modifies four times)
- `(?:[\s–—-]+(?:\d{4}|present))?` - an optional (as there is a `?` at the end) non-capturing (due to `?:`) group matching 1 or 0 occurrences of

  - `[\s–—-]+` -  1 or more whitespaces, `-`, `—` or `–`
  - `(?:\d{4}|present)` - either 4 digits or `present`
- `\)` - a `)` char.

If you plan to match any hyphens use `[\u002D\u058A\u05BE\u1400\u1806\u2010-\u2015\u2E17\u2E1A\u2E3A\u2E3B\u2E40\u301C\u3030\u30A0\uFE31\uFE32\uFE58\uFE63\uFF0D\s]+` instead of `[\s–—-]+`.

Or, to match any 1+ non-word chars at that location, probably, other than `(` and `)`, use `[^\w()]+` instead: `re.compile(r'\(\d{4}(?:[^\w()]+(?:\d{4}|present))?\)', re.I)`.